# Gridview RowCommand not firing when ButtonField clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

**Firefox**:

When the buttonField is click I check `OnRowCommand` and I see that the `commandName` equals "Activar" which is correct.

**Chrome & IE**:

When the button is clicked the `commandName` equals "Select" which isn't correct.

I also have a break point on the first line of `SelectedIndexChanged` and on FF never hits, on Ch and IE it does hit which means the button click event isn't firing

**I'm running**:

- VS12(problem also occurs in most recent versions)
- .NET framework 4.0

**GridView**:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNombreEmp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10" 
                style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:100%" CssClass ="table"
                AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"  BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px"
                CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound ="gvNombreEmp_RowDataBound"
                  OnDataBound ="gvNombreEmp_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="gvNombreEmp_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                OnPageIndexChanging ="gvNombreEmp_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand ="gvNombreEmp_RowCommand">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />

                <Columns>

                     <asp:BoundField DataField="NumeroControl" HeaderText="Número Control" >
                     <HeaderStyle Font-Size="13pt" />
                     <ItemStyle Font-Size="12pt" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NombreEmpresa" HeaderText="Nombre Empresa" >
                     <HeaderStyle Font-Size="13pt" />
                     <ItemStyle Font-Size="12pt" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FC" HeaderText="Fecha Comienzo" >
                     <HeaderStyle Font-Size="13pt" />
                     <ItemStyle Font-Size="12pt" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FE" HeaderText="Fecha Expiración" >
                     <HeaderStyle Font-Size="13pt" />
                     <ItemStyle Font-Size="12pt" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EST" HeaderText="Estatus" >
                     <HeaderStyle Font-Size="13pt" />
                     <ItemStyle Font-Size="12pt" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:ButtonField  CommandName ="Activar" ButtonType="Button" Text ="Desactivar" />

                </Columns>

                <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Size ="Large" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" Font-Bold ="true"/>
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

**RowCommand**:

```
switch(e.CommandName)
{
    case "Activar":

    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working for Chrome but now it doesn't work for FF nor IE. But that's acceptable because, my client only uses Chrome.

What I did was **remove the ButtonType attribute** and the `CommandName` equaled "Activar". I just gotta make sure that if I need to instance it into a variable I have to make sure to cast it as a `LinkButton` and not a regular `Button`